# Correct way to assign variable to incoming view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a simple master-detail app which uses a number of form sheets for modals.

The detail ViewController is a TableViewController with edit buttons in each cell.

I wanted to work out a way to assign the cell's object to the incoming form sheet when the edit button is clicked, so that the form could be presented with the correct data, but I'm not sure if I've done it the correct way...

I've used an `@IBAction` as follows for the edit button:

```
    // DetailViewController.swift

    var activeBooking: Booking? = nil


    @IBAction func onEditBooking(_ sender: Any) {
        let button = sender as! UIButton
        let cell = button.superview!.superview as! BookingCell
        self.activeBooking = cell.booking!
    }
```

and then in my `prepare(for segue:)` method I have the following:

```
    // DetailViewController.swift

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier === "editBookingSegue" {
            let controller = segue.destination as! EditRoomViewController
            controller.booking = activeBooking
        }
    }
```

**Question 1**
Is this ok? I know passing data via segues is legitimate, and it works, but I'm concerned about the execution order of the two methods, would there ever be a race condition where the segue `prepare` method could be called prior to `activeBooking` assignment taking place in the action?

**Question 2**
Also, I don't like using `button.superview!.superview` – seems messy. Is there an easier way to traverse up to the `TableViewCell` for the pressed button? I suppose another option is that I could simplify it by sub-classing `UIButton` in this case so that the `booking` object could also be stored directly on the button.

Comment: Have the cell completely own the button and use a delegate method to pass the action up to your view controller.  Your view controller doesn't need to know about the button.  Have the button call a method on its cell.  The cell then reports the booking request to its delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the cell completely own the button and use a delegate method to pass the action up to your view controller. Your view controller doesn't need to know about the button. Have the button call a method on its cell. The cell then reports the booking request to its delegate.

```
//myCell.swift

@IBAction func onEditBooking(_ sender: Any) {
    bookingDelegate.edit(booking: self.booking)
}

// DetailViewController.swift

func edit(booking: Booking) {
    activeBooking = booking
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "editBookingSegue", sender: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "editBookingSegue" {
         let controller = segue.destination as! EditRoomViewController
         controller.booking = activeBooking
}
```

Or an even better way would be to use the sender value in the prepare for segue method to figure out which button was pressed.  Assign it a tag or something.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "editBookingSegue" {
         let button = sender as! UIButton
         let booking = bookingsArray[button.tag]
         let controller = segue.destination as! EditRoomViewController
         controller.booking = booking
}
```

Comment: I like the second way a lot, really neatens the code up. Out of interest would there have been an issue with the way I had done it, or was it valid, just a little messy?

Comment: @toomanyredirects your way is unsafe. Unfortunately there is no way to guarantee `button.superview.superview` is the view you want. If Apple were to change the view hierarchy and add another view in your code would break. @Dancreek's method is in keeping with standard iOS practices.